# In Jquery code, I want to assign many different selectors to each text value through arrays, .each, index, variable

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables, indexing, text

I have functional code:

```
  $(".A1").text("10");  
  $(".A2").text("20");  
  $(".A3").text("30");
```

but there are so many classes in my functional website for example up to

```
$(".A80").text("800");
```

I want to simplify those code through two arrays with variables where one array are classes... and second one array consists of text values... , now I have non-functional code:

```
var Pw = [".A1",".A2",".A3"];  
var index, len;  
var a = ["10", "20", "30"];  
for (index = 0, len = a.length; index < len; ++index) {             
    $.each(Pw, function(fn){   
        $(Pw[fn]).text(a[index]);  
    });  
}
```

in this code only one value

```
("30")
```

is assigned to all three classes

```
".A1",".A2",".A3",
```

I want to assign

```
10 to A1      
20 to A2      
30 to A3
```

But still I want to have two arrays(not only one array) - one for text value, second for classes... 
 Can anyone help?

Comment: just remove the each and put index in the `Pw` instead of `fn` should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate the `Pw` array, setting the element described by the selector to the corresponding text value from `a`:

```js
var Pw = [".A1",".A2",".A3"];  
var a = ["10", "20", "30"];

Pw.forEach((c, i) => $(c).text(a[i]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A1"></div>
<div class="A2"></div>
<div class="A3"></div>
```

Comment: Wau, functional! What an easy code! Thank you very much Nick!

Comment: Yes, I found a similar case with id... If we replace classes with id so we have following functional code: var Pw = ["#A1","#A2","#A3"]; var a = ["10", "20", "30"]; Pw.forEach((id, i) => $(id).text(a[i]));

Answer (score 0):

Keep your selectors as a string that encompasses all targets concerned. Using an array is limited compared to selectors. If you iterate through a jQuery object (ex. `$(selector)`) use the increment to assign each a number.

Here's a jQuery plugin that is reusable. The following is the signature (example on how to use it):

```
$(selector).serialText(increment, startIncrement = 1);
```

Applied to the situation provided by OP:

```
$('[class^="A"]').serialText(10)

// selector: $(Any element that has a [class that starts with: ^="A"])
// .serialText(..., ...)
// increment: 10
// incrementStart: if not included then the default is used: 1
```

As a jQuery plugin, you can chain other methods to it:

```
$('[class^="A"]').serialText(10).css('color', 'red');
```

BTW, not trying to offend, but that many classes seem excessively unnecessary. You can probably meet your objective using identical classes.

---

#### Demo

```js
$.fn.serialText = function(number, start = 1) {
  $(this).each(function(i) {
    let pattern = (i + start) * number;
    $(this).text(pattern);
  });
  return this;
}

$('[class^="A"]').serialText(10).css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<section class='A1'></section>
<section class='A2'></section>
<section class='A3'></section>
<section class='A4'></section>
<section class='A5'></section>
<section class='A6'></section>
<section class='A7'></section>
<section class='A8'></section>
<section class='A9'></section>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```